# Block parent from deletion when child is available in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, relationship

For a database I want to have some blocking being done, when the parent has a relation to a child, where the child has value. When the parent doesn't have a link, it should be able to delete this. But I can't find out how I need to set it in the relation popup in VB.

In the example I have a table called `Grandparent` and `grandparentID` is linked to `GrandparentID` in table `Parents`. From the table `Parents`, the `parentID` is linked to the table `Children` and their `ParentID`. From the table `Children`, the `ChildrenID` is linked to `childrenID` in the table `Grandchildren`.

Now if for example Grandparent doesn't have a link to Parent, then Parent hasn't a link to Children and also none to Grandchildren. So this parent I want be able to delete, When there is a link to children then it should be blocked from deletion.

However at any moment, I should be able to delete the data, by deleting backwards, first Grandchildren, Children, Parent and then Grandparent.

How can I set this in SQL Server? Do I need to set update- delete rule as None, Cascade or SetNull? Also for the Accept/Reject rule, how to set?

Also is it needed to have those relation as constraint, when the relations is only done between int values?

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using a hierarchy type of architecture? What happens when you need great grandchildren? Are you just going to keep adding more and more tables? I would take a hard look at the design here before going any further. Then I would suggest using t-sql to build your database instead of a visual tool.

Comment: The rule needs to be set to None or No Action

Comment: I see a Help button at the top of that dialogue.  Did you click that?  A Help button should be your first option when you need help.

Comment: @Sean Lange, This is just an example how it looks like. It's not the actual database. And the Grandchild will be the last one.

Comment: @JamieD77, thank you very much. This is helping me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: @j,cilhinney, there is indeed this help button. But MIcrosoft wouldn't be MIcrosoft, if everything would be working :) If I use this help, it jumps to Internet and saying this page isn't to be found :)